# ChartJS with AngularJS - Canvas won't display anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to use the [angular-chartjs](https://github.com/petermelias/angular-chartjs) library but running into some issues. There are no errors on the page. But the canvas is empty.

Anyone has an idea?
I've tried reordering the scripts a few times. I just can't figure it out. :(

Here is the **html**.

```
<html ng-app="profitly">
  <head>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-chartjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper" ng-view>
      <article ng-controller="graph">      
        <cjs-doughnut dataset="someData" options="someOptions" segment-stroke-width="5"></cjs-doughnut>         
      </article>
    </div>
  </body>

<html>
```

And here is the **app initialization**:

```
var app = angular.module('profitly', ['ngRoute', 'chartjs']);
```

And here is the **controller** for this part:

```
app.controller('graph', function($scope) {

  $scope.someData = {
    labels: [
      'Supply', 
      'May', 
      'Jun'
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
    data: [1, 7, 15, 19, 31, 40]
      },
      {
    data: [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36]
      }
    ]
  };

  $scope.someOptions = {
      segmentStrokeWidth: 20,
      segmentStrokeColor: '#000'
  };

 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone else on my hack team figured it out later that day.
Here is the HTML:

```
<article class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 center">
    <canvas id="expenses" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
        <script>
                    var pieData = [
            {
                    value: 20,
                    color:"#878BB6"
            },
            {
                    value : 40,
                    color : "#4ACAB4"
            },
            {
                    value : 10,
                    color : "#FF8153"
            },
            {
                    value : 30,
                    color : "#FFEA88"
            }
    ];
    var pieOptions = {
            segmentShowStroke : false,
            animateScale : true
    }
    var expenses = document.getElementById("expenses").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(expenses).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
    </script>

</article>
```

For more, our [github repo](https://github.com/marineb/smallbizdev) (the view was the "cashflow.html" one) and to see [how it rendered](http://smallbizdev.herokuapp.com/#/cashflow).

Probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: It is not even using angularJs any more. This is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your missing `ng-app` in your `HTML` which would contain which angular app you will be using.

You can put it in the inside one of the `divs` wrapping the graph.

Comment: Sorry, I just made a quick edit. Since it's pulling a view and the index.html, I forgot to add that in the stack overflow snippet. But it's there. See updated code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Imalea did you ever find out what was causing this?

Comment: @ReganPerkins no exactly. I was at a hackathon that day and someone else on my team figured it out. I'll add the answer below.